# Wordpress tag hyperlink creation in the content when a post is saved

Tags: tags

I am managing one website. When I create a post i will enter tag keywords in tag section of post in WordPress. When i save the post I need php/javascript function to get the current post’s tags and create hyperlinks in the content and should save it to database. when a normal user access the post he should see the hyperlinks for the tags of that post. I am using generatepress child theme. I have searched internet, or other platforms But i did not get the code. tag hyperlink creation only happens at admin side when a post saved to database. It should not impact the performance when a normal user access the website and reading the posts.

The below code I tried it always gives 500 internal server error. Can anyone suggest whats wrong in this code and rectify? I have some 100s of posts if I have some automation it would be really great help. I have used taxopress it only identifies tag keywords but does not create the linking content with tags. Any help is appreciated.

```
<?php

function save_post_content_with_hyperlinks( $post_id, $post_content ) {

    // Check if the user is an admin.
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Check if the post ID is null.
    if ( is_null( $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Check if the post content is null.
    if ( is_null( $post_content ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the post tags.
    $post_tags = get_the_tags( $post_id );

    // Check if the post tags are null.
    if ( is_null( $post_tags ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Create an array of hyperlinked tag keywords.
    $hyperlinked_tags = array();
    foreach ( $post_tags as $tag ) {

        // Check if the tag is null.
        if ( is_null( $tag ) ) {
            continue;
        }
    
        $hyperlinked_tag = null;
        if ( ! is_null( $tag ) ) {
            $hyperlinked_tag = '<a href="' . get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>';
        }
        $hyperlinked_tags[] = $hyperlinked_tag;
    }

    // Replace the tag keywords with hyperlinked tag keywords in the post content.
    $post_content = str_replace( $post_tags, $hyperlinked_tags, $post_content );

    // Update the post content in the database.
    wp_update_post( array(
        'ID'           => $post_id,
        'post_content' => $post_content,
    ) );

    // Return the post content with hyperlinks.
    return $post_content;

}
add_filter( 'save_post', 'create_hyperlinks_for_tag_keywords', 10, 2 );
```